# Tag Synonym Request: [respin] -> [remastersys]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

We have a lot of [remastersys](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/remastersys) questions. We have very few [respin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/respin) questions, but they sometimes pop up.

As Respin is a fork (and is pretty similar to) of RemasterSys, it would make sense to have a synonym for the two, especially because the [official site](http://www.remastersys.org/) calls it a fork of the more widely-applicable RemasterSys.

Comment: Forks make changes.. LibreOffice is a fork of OpenOffice, for example, but we both know those aren't the same thing at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd be slightly against this because **respin** isn't just the name for a bit of software, [is its own word](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/respin) that has been used around Linux for a long time to mean a re-imagining or at least a re-imaging  of a distribution.

And in that sense, it's super-east to see see why they've called it this... But I know I've used it in the generic sense before. Merging a generic into a  branded tag feels... Wrong.

<sup>Not with me? What if somebody forked Bash and called it Command-Line? We wouldn't even entertain a merge there. I know it's less extreme here but this isn't a hugely used tag... Do we need to **do** anything?</sup>

Comment: +1 I'd add that since forks often tend to move in different directions there's the distinct possibility that a solution that works in one won't work in the other and merging could easily result in confusion and answers that are both wrong and right (depending on which tine of the fork we are considering)

Comment: Ah. I wasn't aware that respin was the non-brand in this case.